# Remove first N items from RecyclerView and keep right position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

If I remove first N items from `RecyclerView` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`
the `RecyclerView` will jump over on N elements.
I can not call `list.scrollToPosition(position - N items)`. Because list will be jumpy.
How do I keep the right position on a particular item?

Comment: try `notifyItemRangeRemoved` instead of `notifyDataSetChanged`

Comment: also check https://medium.com/@iammert/using-diffutil-in-android-recyclerview-bdca8e4fbb00 to only update items in your `RecyclerView` which are updated/removed and not the existing items. Updating the existing items can also result in the `jumpiness`.